# wpf media element fast forward and fast rewind

Tags: wpf

I have to rewind and forward smoothly the movie using Media Element. It seems to be the player position has to be changed with the timer to do forward and rewind. Any better alternatives.

Thanks and Regards
Raju

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Media element Rewind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880331/media-element-rewind)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about setting the SpeedRatio?  That may work for fastforward. Smooth rewind is difficult, which stems right down to the CODEC.  If you use a media type with a lot of "I-Frames", such as a MJPEG-AVI, you may be able to get smoother rewind (but not perfect) by changing the media position.