# Media element Rewind

Tags: wpf, reverse, playback, mediaelement

In my application, I play a video file using the `MediaElement` control, and I need to have fast forward and rewind options. For fast forward, I increased the `SpeedRatio`, but how can I implement fast rewind? I want to play the video in reverse (in appropriate speed ratio).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the `MediaElement.ScrubbingEnabled` property to true, and pause the MediaElement, and then periodically change its `MediaElement.Position` property backwards to mimic the rewinding behaviour.

Comment: this is not the rewind functionality. In this case, video will be not played in reverse direction. I search the option to play video file in reverse/rewind mode (I don't want to change the position periodically)

Comment: Previously i want to sound when apply rewind functionality but now it is not essential. so in that case your solution works for me.

Comment: @gliderkite I am looking for something similar, i did what you said but the rewinding or the reverse that way is not smooth! Its like missing scenes i would like to have something smoother. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks in advance