# WPF Play Video on Backward

Tags: c#, wpf, video, mediaelement

I have created a Video Player using Media Element in WPF, where I can able to Pause, Play, Stop and Forward Backward to Some particular position.

But I would like to play the video **backward** (opposite direction) when the Play **backward** button clicks and to play **forward** when forward clicks.

Is there any way to achieve this,

Here is my code,

```
 <ToolBar Margin="5">
                <Button x:Name="Open" Click="ControlVideoFlow" Margin="2" Height="30" Width="30" Cursor="Hand">
                    <Image Source="..\..\Images\folder.png" />
                </Button>
                <Separator />
                <Button x:Name="PlayPause" Click="ControlVideoFlow" Margin="2" Height="30" Width="30" Cursor="Hand">
                    <Image x:Name="imgPlayPause" Source="..\..\Images\play.png" />
                </Button>
                <Separator />
                <Button x:Name="Stop" Click="ControlVideoFlow" Margin="2" Height="30" Width="30" Cursor="Hand">
                    <Image Source="..\..\Images\stop.png" />
                </Button>
                <Separator />
                <Button x:Name="PrevFrame" Click="ControlVideoFlow" Margin="2" Height="30" Width="30" Cursor="Hand">
                    <Image Source="..\..\Images\slow_frwd.png" />
                </Button>
                <Separator />
                <Button x:Name="NextFrame" Click="ControlVideoFlow" Margin="2" Height="30" Width="30" Cursor="Hand">
                    <Image Source="..\..\Images\fast_frwd.png" />
                </Button>
                <Separator />
                <Button x:Name="Refresh" Click="ControlVideoFlow" Margin="2" Height="30" Width="30" Cursor="Hand">
                    <Image Source="..\..\Images\refresh.png" />
                </Button>
 </ToolBar>

 <MediaElement Name="mePlayer" LoadedBehavior="Manual" ScrubbingEnabled="True" Stretch="UniformToFill" MediaFailed="mePlayer_MediaFailed" UnloadedBehavior="Manual" />

 <StatusBar Background="#E0DFE1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5">
                <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        </Grid>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
                <StatusBarItem>
                    <TextBlock Name="lblProgressStatus">00:00:00</TextBlock>
                </StatusBarItem>
                <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Cursor="Hand">
                    <Slider Name="sliProgress" IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="sliProgress_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" Thumb.DragStarted="sliProgress_DragStarted" Thumb.DragCompleted="sliProgress_DragCompleted" ValueChanged="sliProgress_ValueChanged" />
                </StatusBarItem>
                <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="2">
                    <ProgressBar Name="pbVolume" Width="50" Height="12" Maximum="1" Value="{Binding ElementName=mePlayer, Path=Volume}" />
                </StatusBarItem>
 </StatusBar>
```

Code Behind,

```
    public bool mediaPlayerIsPlaying = false;
    private bool userIsDraggingSlider = false;
    public string control = string.Empty;
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

    public VideoAnalyser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((mePlayer.Source != null) && (mePlayer.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan) && (!userIsDraggingSlider))
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                sliProgress.Minimum = 0;
                sliProgress.Maximum = mePlayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
                sliProgress.Value = mePlayer.Position.TotalSeconds;
            });
        }
    }

    private void sliProgress_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        mePlayer.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sliProgress.Value);
    }

    private void sliProgress_DragStarted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        userIsDraggingSlider = true;
    }

    private void sliProgress_DragCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        userIsDraggingSlider = false;
        mePlayer.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sliProgress.Value);
    }

    private void sliProgress_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        lblProgressStatus.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sliProgress.Value).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
    }

    private void mePlayer_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Media Failed");
    }

 private async void ControlVideoFlow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            switch (button.Name)
            {
                case "Open":
                    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
                    openFileDialog.Filter = "Media files (*.mp3;*.mpg;*.mpeg;*.mp4)|*.mp3;*.mpg;*.mpeg;*.mp4|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                    openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
                    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
                    {
                        mePlayer.Source = new Uri(openFileDialog.FileName, UriKind.Relative);
                        mePlayer.Play();
                        mePlayer.Pause();
                        mediaPlayerIsPlaying = false;
                        imgPlayPause.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/play.png"));
                        control = "pause";
                        cnvMplayer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        await Task.Delay(300);
                        grdMplayer.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                    break;

                case "PlayPause":
                    if ((mePlayer != null) && (mePlayer.Source != null))
                    {
                        switch (control)
                        {
                            case "":
                                imgPlayPause.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/play.png"));
                                mePlayer.Pause(); control = "pause";
                                mediaPlayerIsPlaying = false;
                                break;
                            case "pause":
                                imgPlayPause.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/pause.png"));
                                mePlayer.Play(); control = "";
                                mediaPlayerIsPlaying = true;
                                break;
                        };
                    }
                    break;

                case "Stop":
                    if ((mePlayer != null) && (mePlayer.Source != null))
                    {
                        mePlayer.Stop();
                        mediaPlayerIsPlaying = false;
                        imgPlayPause.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Sources/Images/play.png"));
                        control = "pause";
                        sliProgress.Value = 0;
                        grdMplayer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        cnvMplayer.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                        mePlayer.Source = null;
                    }
                    break;

                case "PrevFrame":
                    frameReduceorIncrease(-30);
                    break;

                case "NextFrame":
                    frameReduceorIncrease(30);
                    break;

                case "Refresh":
                    TimeSpan position = mePlayer.Position;
                    Uri source = mePlayer.Source;
                    mePlayer.Source = null;
                    mePlayer.Source = source;
                    imgPlayPause.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/play.png"));
                    mePlayer.Play(); control = "pause";
                    mediaPlayerIsPlaying = false;
                    mePlayer.Position = position - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
                    mePlayer.Pause();
                    break;
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play video backwards in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955604/how-to-play-video-backwards-in-wpf)

Comment: Thanks @FabianH. Your answer is really helpful for my situation.